# Pop up on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup

I am trying to make it so when a button is clicked it creates a pop up however I have this error "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\calendar_start.php on line 55**"

Code:

```
    <?php
$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$showmonth= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showmonth);
$showyear= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showyear);

$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth, $showyear);
$pre_days = date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6-(date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, $day_count, $showyear))));

echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="previous_month"><input name="button" type="submit" value="Previous Month" onClick="javascript:last_month();"></div>';
echo '<div class="show_month">'  . date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $showmonth)) . ' ' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"><input name="button" type="submit" value="Next Month" onClick="javascript:next_month();"></div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="week_days">';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sun</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Mon</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Tues</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Wed</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Thur</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Fri</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sat</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';

if ($pre_days != 0) { 
    for($i=1; $i<=$pre_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("familease", $con);

for ($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {

    $date = $i.'/'.$showmonth.'/'.$showyear;
    //echo $date;

    $query = "Select id FROM events WHERE evDate = '$date'";

    $num_rows = 0;
    // check if the query returns anything
    $result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($result) 
    {

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    }

    if($num_rows > 0) {
            <input type="submit" value="Details" 
            onClick="window.open('events.php', 'View',width=300,height=200,menubar=yes,status=yes)"">

    }

    echo '<div class="cal_day">';
    echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';
    if($num_rows > 0) 
        { 
        echo "<div class='openings'><br/>" . $event . "</div>";
        }
    echo '</div>';



} //end of for loop

if ($post_days !=0) {
    for($i=1; $i<=$post_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: This looks like a php error, not html/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no more context all I can see is that you use only simple quotes (`'`) inside your onclick statement. Use double quotes or escape simple quotes inside this  statement such as :

`onClick="window.open('events.php', 'View',width=300,height=200,menubar=yes,status=yes)"`

Comment: @user3242039 Look at your if  statement : `if($num_rows > 0) {
            <input type="submit" value="Details" 
            onClick="window.open('events.php', 'View',width=300,height=200,menubar=yes,status=yes)"">

    }` you forgot `echo` or closing php by using `?>`

Comment: do you mean something like this if($num_rows > 0) {
   echo "<input type="submit" value="Details" onClick="window.open('events.php', 'View',width=300,height=200,menubar=yes,status=yes)"">;
   
 }

Comment: @user3242039 Yes, as you made it the whole file. But don't forget to escape all of your doubles quotes if you make it this way.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still on this. I thought that this was right but it gives me this error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'window' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\calendar_start.php on line 55** heres my code `if($num_rows > 0) {
   echo "<input value='View Event' onClick="window.open('events.php')">";
   
 }`

Can you see where I've gone wrong please

Comment: @user3242039 Write it like this : `echo "<input value=\"View Event\" onClick=\"window.open('events.php')\">";`. I advise you to read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).